# get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args', Django slug RedirectView

Tags: python, django, get, slug

I want to redirect a a view so that it shows the title and the id_number but I get the error in the title.

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from autoslug import AutoSlugField


class EntitiesNew(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    id_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'entities_new'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('entity-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __unicode(self):
        return self.title
```

Views:

```
from entities.models import EntitiesNew
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, RedirectView, ListView, DetailView

class EntityNewView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'entities/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'entities_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return EntitiesNew.objects.order_by('-id_number')[:50]


class EntityDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'entities/detail.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(EntityDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entity']=EntitiesNew.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('id_number', None))
        return context

class EntityRedirectDetailView(RedirectView):

    def get(self, request, args, **kwargs):
        id_number = self.kwargs.get('id_number', None)
        entity = EntitiesNew.objects.get(pk=id_number)
        self.url = '/entities/%s-%s' % (entity.id, entity.slug)
        return super(EntityRedirectDetailView, self).get(request, args, **kwargs)
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from entities import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.EntityNewView.as_view(), name='entities'),   
    url(r'^(?P<id_number>\d+)/$', views.EntityRedirectDetailView.as_view(), name='entity-redirect'),
    url(r'^(?P<id_number>\d+)-(?P<slug>\w+)/$', views.EntityDetailView.as_view(), name='entity-detail'),

]
```

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: this the error I get: TypeError at /entities/12786692/
get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the `*` in the signature of the get function:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, stupid mistake from me... however now if I click on one of the displayed entity I'm redirected to example: entities/Samuel%20Nalot-

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying: that code would redirect you to /entities/<pk>-<slug>/.

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to do... but if I click on the entities displayed as per the get_queryset of the EntityNewView it redirects to the url entities/12786445- skipping the <slug> part...and Page not found (404) is displayed

Comment: Do the entities actually have slugs?

Comment: apparently not... I tried to populate the slug field in the models by using slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', max_length=500) as it can be seen in the models.py...but looks like it is not working properly... I'm noob in Django so if you have any suggestions about how to properly populate the slugs with the title values please advise... also titles are not unique values therefore I want to combine the id_number with the slug...

Comment: If I check the values for slug from the database, ("entities_new_2dbcba41" btree (slug)) the fields are empty and the entity.slug does not return any value so I guess the slug field is not populated correctly.

Comment: Ok I tried to populate the slug fields with: prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}. As per my understanding this dict populates the slug field only when new objects are created using javascript... if I click on the title field in admin the field gets populated correctly. However I have already title values in the database and will not add new objects... since I have many objects it is too time consuming to click on each object title to populate the slug field.. Is there any other way to populate the slug using Django or I have to use sql commands?